# AWS NodeJs SDK cannot delete object

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I'm trying to delete an object on my S3 bucket with the `aws-sdk` for Node.js using [this](https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/3994ff64d1181572d6ae1855862e0816)  `s3.deleteObject` api:

```
async function deleteObjectAsync(bucket, key) {
    try {
        var extras = {
            Bucket: bucket,
            Key: key
        };
        const data = await s3
            .deleteObject(extras)
            .promise();
        return data;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}//deleteObjectAsync
```

used like

```
(async (bucket, keys) => {
    for (const key of keys) {
        const result = await deleteObjectAsync(bucket, key);
        console.log(result);
    }
})(my_bucket, keys);
```

I get - as result - a `DeleteMarker` field and a `VersionId`:

```
{ DeleteMarker: true, VersionId: '2wMteXstTAn6e.rsTS6wHVSerXuUMNLXw' }
```

but the object does not seem to be deleted on the S3 bucket, but marked for deletion.

When using the Python api:

```
def delete_key(bucket, key):
    deleted = True
    try:
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        res = s3.delete_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    except Exception as e:
        print("deleted key:%s error:%s" % (key,e) )
        deleted = False
        pass
    return deleted
```

the file is immediately deleted. Why?

Comment: The behavior you see is exactly the one explained on its [documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#deleteObject-property). I don't understand why it works differently in Python; it should behave the same since they use the same [API endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_DeleteObject.html).

Comment: @guzmonne good point. In fact I wrote a delete object for versioned bucket, but it does not work as expected - https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/0058675d13d1115e7b46b1b66433b327

Comment: If you use the [`deleteObjects`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#deleteObjects-property) method instead, does the behavior changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To successfully delete and object from a `versioned` bucket is super simple, but the documentation isn't very clear on `how` one should do it.

From your own example above, here follows how you could do it:

```
async function deleteObjectAsync(bucket, key) {
  try {
    const params = {
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: key,
      VersionId: 'null'
    };

    return await s3.deleteObject(params).promise();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

The trick is to pass the `'null'` string as VersionId when the object doesn't have a VersionId yet. When it does then you have to delete all the previous versions and then delete the `'null'` version , which is the "original one".

Comment: Thank you, it works. For the sake of glory, and to avoid further headaches to other devs, I have put all possibilities here: https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/3994ff64d1181572d6ae1855862e0816